# How do I obtain a response header value when making a REST call via WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, rest

My code consumes a third party REST service using WCF. The service interface is declared like this:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "SomeNamespace",
     ConfigurationName = "SomeName")]
public interface ICoolService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = @"whatever")]
    void CoolMethod(InputContainer input);
}
```

where `InputContainer` is declared as a `DataContract`:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "whatever")]
public class InputContainer : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    //[DataMember]s inside
}
```

My code instantiates uses `WebChannelFactory` to instantiate a "channel object" and then makes calls to the service via the "channel object"

```
ServiceEndpoint endpoint = ...craft endpoint;     
var factory = new WebChannelFactory<IServiceManagement>( endpoint );
var service = factory.CreateChannel();
service.CoolMethod( new InputContainer() );
```

and it works quite well.

Now the problem... The documentation to that service says that the service returns a response with `x-some-cool-header` and empty body.

How do I obtain the value of that response header (preferably as a return value of `CoolMethod()`)?

Comment: Do you mean how do you add a header to your response? What client are you using to call the service? You would need to post the client portion of the code. What documentation are you referring to?

Comment: @JamesRalston I tried to clarify my setup. My code consumes a third-party service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to change the interface declaration such that the method returns `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message`:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = @"whatever")]
Message CoolMethod(InputContainer input);
```

then once method invokation is complete you get a `Message` object which contains the HTTP response with the headers:

```
var invokationResult = service.CoolMethod( new InputContainer() );
var properties = message.Properties;
var httpResponse = 
    (HttpResponseMessageProperty)properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];
var responseHeaders = httpResponse.Headers;
var coolHeader = reponseHeaders["x-some-cool-header"];
```