# How do I use OperationContract to capture a response header from POST request?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, datacontractserializer

I have the following WCF wrappers to call a REST service:

```
[DataContract]
public class InterestingResponse : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    [MessageHeader(Name="x-interesting-id")]
    public string InterestingId { get; set; }

    public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract()]
public interface IManagement
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = @"somePathHere")]
    InterestingResponse DoInteresting();
}
```

The request is being sent to the service and completes successfully. The HTTP response has empty body and `x-interesting-id` header. I want the client side code to return an instance of `InterestingResponse` with `InterestingId` being set to the value of `x-interesting-id` from the response.

Once `IManagement.DoInteresting()` returns on the client the null reference is returned because well, the response was empty, nothing to deserialize, I guess.

How would I have an object returned instead with the header value deserialized as object member?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message` as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29773912/57428). Change method declaration to:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = @"somePathHere")]
Message DoInteresting();
```

then once invokation is complete the `Message` object will contain the HTTP response with HTTP headers:

```
var invokationResult = service.DoInteresting();
var properties = message.Properties;
var httpResponse = 
    (HttpResponseMessageProperty)properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];
var responseHeaders = httpResponse.Headers;
var interestingHeader = reponseHeaders["x-interesting-id"];
```